# Bootstrap glyphicon-cog actually shows glyphicon-envelope?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

This is super strange, per their guidelines [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons), I added a span with `glyphicon glyphicon-cog` .... However, when loading my page, it actually shows the envelope - which is `glyphicon glyphicon-envelope`. Exactly how does this happen and what can I do to fix it?

I've tried adding the envelope... Because maybe they swapped it around. But it still looks like an envelope, the same.

Here's what `glyphicon glyphicon-cog` ends up showing:

[image]

It's added like this:

```
<div className="dropdown">
      <button className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <h6 style={{fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
          fontSize: "12px", fontVariant: "small-caps"}}>
          settings </h6>
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" />
      </button>
      <ul className="dropdown-menu" style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
          <li>
              <h5 style={{fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif", fontSize: "12px", fontVariant: "small-caps"}}>
                  user: {this.state.data.username} </h5>
          </li>
          <li style={{display: "inline-block"}}>
              <button onClick={this.resetLayout} className="btn btn-default" style={{fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
                  fontSize: "12px", fontVariant: "small-caps"}}>
                  reset layout </button>
          </li>
          <li style={{display: "inline-block"}}>
              <button className="btn btn-default" style={{fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
                  fontSize: "12px", fontVariant: "small-caps"}}>
                  <a href="/logout" style={{color: "black"}}> logout</a></button>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: make sure you're not setting `text-transform:uppercase` as important on the element, as most icon fonts are case sensitive

Comment: @haxxxton i haven't used that at all, so i dont think that is it! It's just super weird behavior. Would've made sense if none of them were working..

Comment: You need to close the `<span>` tag with **`</span>`** and not `<span ... />`

Comment: can you confirm you have downloaded and are using the latest version of the font please

Comment: @JazZ didn't make a difference(and it shouldn't I guess).  I am wondering if webpack doesn't compile my fonts properly... checking it out now.

Comment: Can you inspect the element and check out what it's rendered as?

Comment: In html, you'll need to use `class` instead of `className`. Could you give it a try, please ?

Comment: It's react, `className` is the proper syntax to call css classes

Comment: Ok, sorry... Good luck dude. ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like:-

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that envelope really coming from bootstrap?

Because it looks different.

You should check in the developer tools, what is actually overriding the `:before` of that `span className="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"`

And it should be something else, not bootstrap.

If it does not fix, you can use the `font-family` as `Glyphicon` and `content` as the cog's character code manually.

You can find the code here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/glyphicons.less

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon-class">glyphicon glyphicon-envelope</span> </li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon-class">glyphicon glyphicon-cog</span> </li>
</ul>
```